# javascript:resizeTo(1024,768);

Tags: javascript

A colleague suggested to the testers they enter **javascript:resizeTo(1024,768);** into the address bar after starting the app to test it in the smallest browser dimensions for which we are responsible.  However, shortly after executing this command (in IE6), the backspace and delete keys stopped working and users could not cut-and-paste.

Why is this happening?  In general, should users avoid enter **javascript:xxx** commands into the address bar?  Thanks.

Comment: Shameless plug: http://setmy.browsersize.com

Comment: Updated my answer with more info, hope that helps.

Comment: I appreciate the shameless plug, but we run our app on a network disconnected from the internet.

Comment: Apparently FF6&7 have [disallowed `javascript:` uri's from the location bar to prevent social engineering attacks](http://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=6488&p=27991). [Bug report link](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=656433).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a kind of [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) that he's suggested typing in directly. I wouldn't expect it to cause any trouble, although with IE6 I wouldn't guarantee that the address bar having changed wouldn't cause a problem. To get around that, just give them a page with

```
<a href='javascript:resizeTo(1024,768);'>bookmark this</a>
```

...on it and have them right-click and bookmark that. Then they can use it from their bookmarks without changing the address bar.

But you'd be better off with a proper resizing tool. Search for "[browser resizer](http://www.google.com/search?q=browser+resizer)" to find some (I can't recommend a specific one).

Comment: +1.  Sometimes I'll type some `javascript:` command into my address bar (usually to alert/dump some information).  I can honestly say I've never run into any problems with delete/backspace keys.  I've also tried to repro your issue on WinXP SP3 but no luck.

Comment: Thanks, @Andy.  Probably another IE6 bug.

Answer (score 0):

I bet it was pure chance. Typing that code into the location bar is roughly equivalent to executing it from the page source and that executed statement only resizes current window.

Comment: Several users have repeated the problem pointing to several different environments/deployments.  I tried to repeat the problem for an hour to no avail before I discovered the testers were updating their address bars.  Twenty seconds later, I repeated the problem.